# sql server inner join two tables and filter with two fields, getting extra records

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am having issue with getting an SELECT with INNER JOIN between two tables to get the correct output.

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSON_TABLE
WHERE MYSOMETHINGID = 123
```

The results are

```
ID   PERSON_ID     PERSON     IS_SELECTED    IS_BACKUP  MYSOMETHINGID 
2    -1            PERSON1    0              0          123
3    12            PERSON2    0              1          123
4    13            PERSON3    1              0          123
5    15            PERSON4    0              1          123
6    22            PERSON5    0              0          123

select *
from ASSIGNED_TABLE
where MYSOMETHINGID = 123

ID   PERSON_ID     PERSON     MYSOMETHINGID 
3    12            PERSON2    123
4    13            PERSON3    123
5    15            PERSON4    123
```

I want to inner join both company and select only the record with IS_SELECTED = 1 and if the record from PERSON_TABLE exists in ASSIGNED_TABLE

Here is my queries

```
select *
from ASSIGNED_TABLE AT inner join
     PERSON_TABLE PT
     on PT.IS_SELECTED = 1 AND AT.PERSON_ID = PT.PERSON_ID
where AT.MYSOMETHINGID = 123

ID   PERSON_ID     PERSON     MYSOMETHINGID   IS_SELECTED   IS_BACKUP
3    12            PERSON2    123             1             0
4    13            PERSON3    123             1             0
5    15            PERSON4    123             1             0
```

I was expecting PERSON13 since it is the only record with IS_SELECTED = 1. I don't understand why I am getting 3 records instead of 1 and strangely the IS_SELECTED is 1 for all 3 records and 0 for all IS_BACKUP

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see how that query could return those results. Please a complete repro, including DDL statement, INSERTs for data, and expected results.

When you do, it's likely you will find your problem for yourself.  If not, it will be easy for people to examine your issue.

Comment: The only way I can see you getting those results is if you have different connections w/ uncommitted updates and are executing them on different connections or against different databases w/ different data.  Given presented data, the query should operate as desired.  So something else is going on. or if Person_table has person_ID listed multiple times with different mysomethignIds...

Comment: how many records in person_table have person_ID 13?  Just 1? if more then you have a problem with your query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to also join on `mysomethingid`:

```
select *
from ASSIGNED_TABLE AT inner join
     PERSON_TABLE PT
     on PT.IS_SELECTED = 1 AND
        AT.PERSON_ID = PT.PERSON_ID AND
        AT.MYSOMETHINGID = PT.MYSOMETHINGID
where AT.MYSOMETHINGID = 123;
```

Comment: Hi, I don't need to add mysomethingid. It is a test to filter out a group of records for my test. That ID should bring back 1 record and not all 3

Comment: @John . . . You need to apply the filter on both tables, and a `JOIN` is the simplest way to do that.  Otherwise, your sample data has no relevance to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *
  from ASSIGNED_TABLE AT 
 inner join PERSON_TABLE PT
  on AT.PERSON_ID = PT.PERSON_ID
 where PT.IS_SELECTED = 1 AND MYSOMETHINGID = 123
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to select only rows where is_selected = 1

```
select *
from ASSIGNED_TABLE AT inner join
 PERSON_TABLE PT ON
 AT.PERSON_ID = PT.PERSON_ID
where AT.MYSOMETHINGID = 123 AND PT.IS_SELECTED = 1
```